# chrome.contextMenus exclude URL?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Im using `chrome.contextMenus` documentUrlPatterns to filter where to show the context menu.

I tried prepending '-' to the patterns but that doesnt change anything...

```
function recreateStuff(){
        if(logoncmid!=-1){}
        var hosts=[];
        var ihosts=[];
        for (var i = savedData.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          hosts.push(savedData[i].host);
          ihosts.push("-"+savedData[i].host);
          //console.log(savedData[i]);
        };
        // hosts created ...
        chrome.contextMenus.update(logoncmid,{documentUrlPatterns: hosts});
        chrome.contextMenus.update(regcmid,{documentUrlPatterns: ihosts});


}
```

Is it possible to make an exclude list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about a hack ? :)

```js
var windowTopTab = [];
var curWin = 1;
var curUrl = "";

function fetchCurUrl() {
  if (!windowTopTab[curWin]) return;
  chrome.tabs.get(windowTopTab[curWin], function(tab) {
    curUrl = url;
  });
}

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
  windowTopTab[activeInfo.windowId] = activeInfo.tabId;
  fetchCurUrl();
  recreateStuff();
});
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(windowId) {
  curWin = windowId;
  fetchCurUrl();
  recreateStuff();
});
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (windowTopTab[curWin])
    if (windowTopTab[curWin] == tabId) {
      fetchCurUrl();
      recreateStuff();
    }
});

var contextm = chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "* Fill RegForm",
  contexts: ["editable"],
  onclick: genericOnClick
});

function recreateStuff() {
  var curHN = getHostname(curUrl);
  var reg = true;
  for (var i = savedData.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (savedData[i].host == curHN) reg = false;
  }

  if (reg) {
    chrome.contextMenus.update(contextm, {
      title: "* RegForm",
      onclick: genericOnClick
    });
  } else {
    chrome.contextMenus.update(contextm, {
      title: "* LoginForm",
      onclick: genericOnClick2
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is currently possible, since `documentUrlPatterns` takes an array of [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) and there is no way to express a negative match pattern.

You might [open a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) for a mechanism to express excluded match patterns, [as is done for content scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#match-patterns-globs) with `exclude_matches` and `exclude_globs`.

Comment: any idea if this changed since 2013?